# What is the difference between NS record and SOA record in DNS entry?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dns-zone

I am trying to understand the difference between NS record and SOA record. As NS record is supposed to store a primary authoritative nameserver and secondary authoritative nameserver as a backup of data. And according to RFC of DNS, SOA stores "the name server that was the original or primary source of data for this zone" in MNAME. Why does SOA record sometimes different from NS record? Example:

```
htw-berlin.de.          460     IN      SOA     infoblox1.htw-berlin.de. net-rz.htw-berlin.de. 2009142669 10800 3600 2419200 900
htw-berlin.de.          20965   IN      NS      infobloxv.htw-berlin.de.
htw-berlin.de.          20965   IN      NS      dns-2.dfn.de.
```

In this case: `infoblox1.htw-berlin.de.` != `infobloxv.htw-berlin.de.`

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record) article hints at the reason, but to make it explicit: the `MNAME`  designates the primary master name server for a zone.

That *can be* and often *is* one of the public authoritative name servers, that are also found in the NS records and/or the WHOIS record, but it can also name a different DNS server. Such a configuration is often called a  ***hidden master***.

## Hidden Master

A hidden master is a name server that is not advertised and does not appear in any `NS` records. In other words, it is not designated  publicly on the Internet as a name server for your domain and does not answer any queries from the internet. The hidden master’s purpose is to provide zone transfers to a set of "secondary" name servers that *are* known publicly as authoritative for your domain and answer queries.

It is considered to have some operational and security benefits:  Often the "hidden master" is protected by a firewall and access is restricted, or the hidden master is part of your internal network. And that is where the domain administrator will manage the DNS records. Reloads and restarts of the hidden master do not impact resolution of your domain. And your DNSEC private keys will be better protected.

Other say consider such a setup something confusing and contrary to Internet standards.

https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/dns/configuration/hidden_master.shtml

(In this case I could assume that an organisation uses an Infoblox appliance/solution for their internal DNS and rather than using additional appliances directly to manage their public DNS, they manage their internet domain and public DNS records with the same internal appliance.
Or they have an even more complex solution like this one: https://docs.infoblox.com/space/BloxOneDDI/290685979/BloxOne+DDI+as+the+Hidden+Primary+Master
)

Comment: Excellent answer, but could you touch DNSSEC, too? The benefits of using a hidden master become more clear when it is the only server that knows the private keys.

Answer (score 2):

NS record is the nameservers, the servers which hold the DNS zones

SOA is start of authority, a SOA record has the config when the DNS zone gets refreshed and updated and replicated to all other DNS servers in the world when it's internet connected

For example the SOA of google.com is

```
google.com.     10 IN SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. (
                595350753  ; serial
                900        ; refresh (15 minutes)
                900        ; retry (15 minutes)
                1800       ; expire (30 minutes)
                60         ; minimum (1 minute)
                )
```

So when Google updates a DNS record it will take an interval of 15 minutes before the DNS servers communicate it to global DNS infrastructure

For htw berlin it's

```
htw-berlin.de.      21600 IN SOA infoblox1.htw-berlin.de. net-rz.htw-berlin.de. (
                2009142669 ; serial
                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                900        ; minimum (15 minutes)
                )
```

That the names are different could be a CNAME or some DNS proxy

This is a strange one, I have no idea why it's different

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.15 <<>> ANY +additional +multiline +trace +dnssec net-rz.htw-berlin.de. @8.8.4.4
;; global options: +cmd
.           29241 IN NS a.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS b.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS c.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS d.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS e.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS f.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS g.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS h.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS i.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS j.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS k.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS l.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN NS m.root-servers.net.
.           29241 IN RRSIG NS 8 0 518400 (
                20240117050000 20240104040000 30903 .
                NG0lAPqTSOmSW02oV6+f62WF6tTlnlVozhdRPo40JBED
                0AViqQL348xXq5gTWrejUE0Dp0x0Pp8H5/NZMCVeYtyB
                BUxcmwLRs7IhltMNQjkOXH2yDYyXi+bup7KMSthEHDiV
                dE3e2B58mFHEumemZxPfnKOEMrpAdnb15LvFZkfqSE4L
                d4CzpXXWO/fAWtD3NnmPlAc9LX7+woKsPquK40CLQQg3
                sY9/wcoIa3Z3VTr32o9R4iBFZD5eAhCBl3gPabR7KQF1
                XR9Fnu9l0kREXt5gu8SN/a26KuhTb51bN9xiqivTJnZZ
                3YIQEts/aJehRbDDzpMh5U+eAEje8KRjYw== )
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4) in 1 ms

de.         172800 IN NS a.nic.de.
de.         172800 IN NS f.nic.de.
de.         172800 IN NS l.de.net.
de.         172800 IN NS n.de.net.
de.         172800 IN NS s.de.net.
de.         172800 IN NS z.nic.de.
de.         86400 IN DS 26755 8 2 (
                F341357809A5954311CCB82ADE114C6C1D724A75C039
                5137AA3978035425E78D )
de.         86400 IN RRSIG DS 8 1 86400 (
                20240117220000 20240104210000 30903 .
                F/NZZ0AGqQkdyU9NZbFi9Gsc/zZL+XIj37gRCr7DVxsW
                d3hhXNCHKFwo9Z99StbcDKnlxAWUEdCWZnJ/pPaaV6ku
                AMScJDFMjZxq+KVscpn4iqd+70V9s+awrAWcCyJpQeKF
                xPEG3v+eCDQ1Nu4FX/yyvpwSOW6fXWSTdTIoS0gcEStY
                FiMZoAjWaMCi9e6Y4FIgUpM+s+a3G5g9QwKxKWrovknR
                pOuaCYZftu1fijC3eb5A/x1cUz9VkonQyKt9Abs4Vjrt
                pqZ8vwsD6H91dcqJQSP8gd9L3tqgb6H3Xynvf60iAMjL
                IihPFZuXuw5m0ATdY0GZ/5SQLRz4rm43YA== )
;; Received 754 bytes from 192.203.230.10#53(e.root-servers.net) in 3 ms

htw-berlin.de.      86400 IN NS infobloxv.htw-berlin.de.
htw-berlin.de.      86400 IN NS dns-2.dfn.de.
tjlb7qbojvmlf1s6gdriru7vsms1lg16.de. 7200 IN NSEC3 1 1 15 CA12B74ADB90591A (
                TJLF6JN42VL7A95RC3U0K1AOGLKQJ53O
                NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM )
tjlb7qbojvmlf1s6gdriru7vsms1lg16.de. 7200 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 7200 (
                20240117032622 20240103015622 11943 de.
                tw3xisSs186MI0yplC9n5lXR+it6Rb48064JuklcJI7v
                GYLrHB8ZHCLhyvlJ2LDVoCs92Jc/bMedoU000WnAPrNQ
                9nd3e7YGBuXPFbENlmOznjsbZcJTK9SJTOKsc3r8IMD/
                8ll8QjauHfILb1SAgEVdEBNgpJYY6tBU7STVZCo= )
vkljdt8c5h3gkigc5hnc82m0ppf0n5to.de. 7200 IN NSEC3 1 1 15 CA12B74ADB90591A (
                VKLNAHSBEO2AUU8FLR4GF2OQ9I9R8GHH
                A RRSIG )
vkljdt8c5h3gkigc5hnc82m0ppf0n5to.de. 7200 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 7200 (
                20240116055819 20240102042819 11943 de.
                mmaUzsIJTVG+p/P21jw/ZEGmt7o9bmhgxQDGSG3pg6FH
                /39hIDFnSpXQvRWDU3vXRZ7CEy0MUcmehkdoYDzOnMnz
                42srAdHUxENbbSpAFO2A7Y0zZpExBE8jaCVBt/sUuXZv
                TgiYmA0t69kZgyR6Atk9OQmc1H9gMcUww+pgUHE= )
;; Received 616 bytes from 194.0.0.53#53(a.nic.de) in 33 ms

;; Connection to 2001:638:d:b102::1#53(2001:638:d:b102::1) for net-rz.htw-berlin.de. failed: network unreachable.
htw-berlin.de.      900 IN SOA infoblox1.htw-berlin.de. net-rz.htw-berlin.de. (
                2009142669 ; serial
                10800      ; refresh (3 hours)
                3600       ; retry (1 hour)
                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                900        ; minimum (15 minutes)
                )
;; Received 95 bytes from 193.174.75.54#53(dns-2.dfn.de) in 102 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that all fields of the SOA record are there to indicate where and how **updates** should be made.

- The 2nd field of SOA (the RNAME) is the email address of the "host master" – i.e. the person who is responsible for making updates (originally, "host master" was the job title for the person responsible for maintaining the ARPANET HOSTS.TXT table).
- It follows that the 1st field of SOA (the MNAME) is supposed to indicate *where* one would log in to for making edits to zone files, as traditional AXFR-based zone replication means only one nameserver is actually "writable" (all others are read-only replicas).
- Almost all of the remaining SOA fields, too, are there just to deal with AXFR-based replication – with MINTTL being the only exception.

(It might be relevant to note that in the early days, long before wide availability of globally distributed anycast DNS hosting, it was *not uncommon* to have some other institution host secondary nameservers on your behalf, for redundancy in case your own network/AS went down… and if your network was small, it was perhaps also not uncommon to have some other institution be your primary nameserver too. So if you had Foo University hosting your primary DNS and Foobar Institution hosting a replica, the SOA field would help you remember whom to contact whenever updates needed to be made.)

As other answers say, it's relatively normal for the 'master' server listed in SOA to be omitted from NS; it could perfectly well be a "hidden master" that is only used as a replication source and doesn't directly serve live data. In practice, this field is purely informational and replication doesn't actually use it either (the source server is configured manually).

With the later addition of dynamic DNS updates (DNS UPDATE), the SOA MNAME field is in fact used to indicate which server is the one that all dynamic updates must be sent to. For example, if you use `nsupdate` you'll see that it doesn't care about NS but always sends the update to whichever nameserver is listed in SOA.

(Even within Active Directory, for example, despite the fact that AD zones are usually hosted on AD DCs all of which are writable thanks to AD's multi-master replication, Windows nevertheless uses the domain's SOA field to determine a single server for the purpose of sending dynamic updates.)

As a final note, before push-based AXFR (DNS NOTIFY) was widely implemented, traditional replication was done on a schedule (which is *also* defined via SOA record) – every X minutes, the replica servers would refresh from their source (generally the 'master' server, although multiple tiers are possible). So even if the replication schedule was something like "every 6 hours", the server listed in SOA MNAME could be relied upon to have the latest data (e.g. if one wanted to check whether an update took effect).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is a lot simpler... SOA is Start Of Authority, the nameserver which is deemed authoritative for the domain. NS are NameServer records, the machines you ask for that information. For most people, the SOA can be, usually is, one of the name servers; but a big organization like Google will often have a different machine to hold its zone file, and the NS machines simply query the SOA machine periodically to make sure they are all on the same page.

I don't know the logic behind this, but I suppose that for a heavily loaded system like Google it would make some sense to not have the SOA host buried with NS requests when the other nameservers needed to request an update. It might also be a way of hardening your zone files, if the SOA machine is set to not accept updates from any external source.